# Probability theory - COINTOSS on SPOJ

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an issue with following problem: https://www.spoj.com/problems/COINTOSS/

I use following code which (in my console) returns correct answers:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int cases = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            string[] answers = new string[cases];

            for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++)
            {
                string full_input = Console.ReadLine();
                string[] splited_input = full_input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                double n = Convert.ToDouble(splited_input[0]);
                double m = Convert.ToDouble(splited_input[1]);

                double a = Math.Pow(2, n + 1);
                double b = Math.Pow(2, m + 1);

                double result = Math.Round(a - b, 2);

                answers[i] = result.ToString("0.00");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < cases; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(answers[j]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

However, on SPOJ, I get "Wrong Answer" error. Any idea why? Is my algorithm wrong?

Comment: Algorithm and formatting look correct. But is the code handling big numbers like `2^1001`?

Comment: Changed all numbers that take part in calculations to double data type and added rounding to 2 integers (as seen in OP), yet still getting "Wrong Answer". I have zero ideas why this could happen.

Comment: I believe a double can hold 64 bits. We need 1002 bits for 2^1001. Maybe try a big integer library?